# Unvectorize This Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a MALTAB function:
    find(x > [x(1)-1;x(1:n-1)] & x > [x(2:n);x(n)-1]);

How can I unvectorize this? I am not quite sure what it is even testing for!

Ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what find(X>somearray & x>someotherarray) means. Is it testing for is any x, or is all x?

Btw, x itself is an array!

Comment: Yes, but I get CAT arguments dimension are not consistent when I use x = [2,3,4,5,0,9,1]

Comment: `x` should be a column vector, so try with `x = [2,3,4,5,0,9,1]'`

Comment: This code returns the indices where `x(i)` is larger than its neighbors, i.e. `x(i) > x(i - 1) && x(i) > x(i + 1)`, with some special handling for `i == 1` and `i == numel(X)` where only a single neighbor exists.

Comment: it is not clear what are your inputs then, and I think you need to rephrase the question, say what you tried what the problem was (the error you just mentioned), what are the inputs (x is a vector \ 3d-array etc). The way the question is phrased now is below SO standard, as the down-votes also suggest.

Comment: Thank you erikced. At least you are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
result = []

for i = 1:n
    if i == 1 % special case, since x(-1) does not exist
        x_below = x(1) - 1;
    else
        x_below = x(i - 1);
    end
    if i == n % special case, since x(n + 1) does not exist
        x_above = x(n) - 1;
    else
        x_above = x(i + 1);
    end
    if x(i) > x_below && x(i) > x_above
        result = [result, i]; %add found index to result
    end
end
```

So as Eric mentioned, it returns the index of all elements in x that are larger then their neighbors. For `x(1)`, a 'fake' lower neighbor of `x(1) - 1` is made, so that `x(1)` is always larger. Index 1 is thus returned if x(1) > x(2). A similar trick is done for `x(n)`.

Comment: ^^This works perfectly! Thank you Bas and Eric. You guys rock!